# Python Regular Expression for a paragraph

Tags: python, regex

Hi i have this as my testing string:

```
<image>
<title>CNN.com - Technology</title>
<link>http://www.cnn.com/TECH/index.html?eref=rss_tech</link>
```

and i want to select 'Technology' from it using a python regular expression, however i need it specific so that it uses `<image>` and `<link>`. So far the expression i have is:

```
'<title[^>]*>CNN.com - (.*?)</title>'
```

this expression works to select 'Technology', this is correct however i am unsure how to specialise my code using  `<image>` and `<link>` in the expression. For example i need something along the lines of this regular expression `'<image><title[^>]*>CNN.com - (.*?)</title><link>'` that would actually work to produce the same result of 'Technology?

Comment: At this point I'd recommend the visit of https://regex101.com/#python - an online regex tester with python code generation - `<image>.*<title[^>]*>CNN.com - (.*?)<\/title>.*<link>`

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is not bad but you need to escape the slash in `</title>` with a backslash and it does not match because of the newlines in your string.

Newlines are whitespaces (like space, tabulation... \s is equivalent to [ \t\n\r\f\v] when the UNICODE flag is not set), so you can use \s to match them.

I assume you're using python3 but it does not matter.

```
s = """<image>
<title>CNN.com - Technology</title>
<link>http://www.cnn.com/TECH/index.html?eref=rss_tech</link>"""
r = r"<image>[\s]*<title[^>]*>CNN.com - (.*?)<\/title>[\s]*<link>"
m = re.search(r, s)
print(m.group(0))
print(m.group(1))
```

group(1) is "Technology".

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :

```
(<image>\n<title>CNN.com - )(.*?)(<\/title>\n.*)
```

Group number 2 would be `Technology`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'single line' option for regex, you name newlines with `.`. So, you can do:

```
<image>.<title[^>]*>CNN.com - (.*?)</title>.<link>
```